Laravel Nova 5 error registerStoreModules in app.js
I love Nova and it is working really well for my project, and I upgraded to Nova 5 a few days ago.  Not sure it is related to the upgrade, but every time I refresh a page or go directly to a URL, I get a blank page and there is an error in app.js:

Using the sidebar menu to navigate still works.

did you publish properly? php artisan nova:publish --force

once published clear the config and cache.

I had the same issue and had to revert back to Nova 4

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
